# JSONP request in Adobe Air

Tags: jquery, air, adobe, jsonp

I'm working on an Abobe Air application where I need to make a request for some data to my MySQL server. I made some simple services in PHP and used jQuery and JSONP to call and retrieve data from them. In my web browser the solution below works perfectly, but when trying it in Air it doesn't seem to perform the Ajax-request.

I've confirmed that jQuery is working in Air and I've confirmed that the callService() function works as well. However, it seems to just stop before the Ajax call is made. The success and jsonpCallback functions never fire.

For the last few hours I've been searching and trying various solutions, but I just can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

```
function callService(id) {
        id = id.toString();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {key: 'somekey', serviceid: id},
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            url: "http://myremotedomain.com/services.php",
            success: function () {
            }
        });
    }

    function jsonpCallback(data){
        //Do stuff with the data
    }
```